# posting data into multiple queue aws services

Tags: php, yii2, amazon-sqs

I working with Queue Component for Yii2 from reference https://libraries.io/github/cybercog/yii2-queue

I wants to know that how can i post data into 2-3 different queue url for different feature

for that i have to configure 2-3 user here in below configuration code plsease let me know how can i provide multiple url in configuration

```
'components' => [
'queue' => [
    'class' => 'UrbanIndo\Yii2\Queue\SqsQueue',
    'module' => 'task',
    'url' => 'https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/123456789012/queue',
        'config' => [
            'key' => 'AKIA1234567890123456',
            'secret' => '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890',
        'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
    ],
]]
```

or how can i set url while posting data into queue

```
Yii::$app->queue->post(new Job(['route' => ['sync' => 'emailSync'], 'data' => $options]));
```